# '... a journalist who is used to ...' vs. '... a journalist who uses to

Tags: word-meaning, idioms, passive-voice, past-participles

> To an economist or a journalist who ***is used*** to thinking of a decade as long enough for entire theories to rise and fall, an age is the longest period imaginable; durable ideas can be age-old and this age is synonymous with 'this world' or 'everything'.

Can anyone confirm whether ***is used*** is used correctly in that passage?

Shouldn't it be '... who *uses* to ...'?

Comment: *Be used to [noun phrase]* is an idiom.

Answer (score 5):

"Is used to" is correct. Here "is used to" means "is accustomed to". The writer means that these journalists conventionally think in this way.

Note this is a very different meaning of the word "used" than if you say an object is used in a certain way.

"This hammer is used to build furniture." That is the purpose to which I put the hammer.

"My brother is used to building furniture." This is something that my brother does regularly.

You would not say "a journalist who uses to". That is grammatically incorrect. You could say "a journalist who uses X to do Y", like "a journalist who uses a pencil to take notes". But that's the second meaning, "utilizes", not the first, "is accustomed to".

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but to clarify your answer, *is used to* is idiomatic. What you've actually explained here is that the other use of *use(d)* is transitive; it always takes an object in that context. So, I wanted to include that term in your answer.

Comment: +1 However, *uses to VERB* is not "grammatically incorrect", but obsolete; it was only about the middle of the 18th century that this usage became confined to the past tense, *used to*, in the active voice.

Comment: Also note that in many places, "used" typically is pronounced differently in the two example sentences.  /juːzd/ (yo͞ozd) for the hammer, /juːzt/ (yo͞ozt) for the brother.

Comment: @StoneyB Do you mean that "uses to" denoted an ongoing habit in the present, the way "used to" now denotes habitual past behavior?

Comment: @StoneyB I would say that "gone since the middle of the 18th century" pretty much adds up to grammatically incorrect. Where do you set the cut off date? 300 years? 400?

Comment: @StoneyB, "uses to" in the present tense is so uncommon in contemporary English that I think most native speakers would not understand it. For purposes of ELL, I think that makes it fair to say "incorrect" rather than "obsolete".

Comment: @Kaz I think Stoney is just pointing out that there's a difference between something that has always been wrong and something that has fallen out of use. It's good to know which one it is, I think, especially if being aware of the way something used to be used helps the learner understand the topic of discussion more easily.

Comment: @WendiKidd "used to be used" -- excellent example for this thread.